# How do I check this condition in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

Eg. If I have a command

```
<package> list --all
```

Output of the command:

```
Name  ID   
abc    1   
xyz    2
```

How can I check if the user input is the same as the name in the list, using a shell script. Something like this:

```
if ($input== $name in command )
   echo "blabla"
```

Comment: If the current user is *anywhere in the list at all*? If the current user is the only one in the list? Something else? And by "user input" -- do you mean you want to read from stdin? Command line argument? Something else?

Comment: Yes ..by user input I mean read . No current user is not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
name=$1
<package> list --all | egrep -q "^$name[ \t]" 
result=$?
```

The somewhat dubious notation of `package` is from the question and is a kind of placeholder.

The result will be 0 on success and 1 on failure.

If the name is literally "name" it will match the headline, and if blanks might be in the name, it will be more complicated.

```
egrep -q "^$name[ \t]"
```

means 'quiet', don't print the matching case on the screen.
$name holds the parameter, which we assigned in the beginning.

The "^" prevents "bc" to match - it means "beginning of line".
The "[ \t]" captures blank and tab as end of word markers.

Comment: Do you mean `result=$?`?

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternate approach (which allows reading and testing more than one value without rerunning your `list` command or needing to do an O(n) lookup):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $BASH_VERSION in
  '')       echo "This script requires bash 4.x (run with non-bash shell)" >&2; exit 1;;
  [0-3].*)  echo "This script requires bash 4.x (run with $BASH_VERSION)" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

declare -A seen=( )                 # create an empty associative array
{
  read -r _                         # skip the header
  while read -r name value; do      # loop over other lines
    seen[$name]=$value              # ...populating the array from them
  done
} < <(your_program list --all)      # ...with input for the loop from your program

# after you've done that work, further checks will be very efficient:
while :; do
  printf %s "Enter the name you wish to check, or enter to stop: " >&2
  read -r name_in                      # read a name to check from the user
  [[ $name_in ]] || break              # exit the loop if given an empty value
  if [[ ${seen[$name_in]} ]]; then     # lookup the name in our associative array
    printf 'The name %q exists with value %q\n' "$name_in" "${seen[$name_in]}"
  else
    printf 'The name %q does not exist\n' "$name_in"
  fi
done
```